# how to print each value of list on next line in python

Tags: python, string, list, printing, element

Code snippet :

[image: img]

```
task = input("Add task to do ")
list  = task.split()
print("Your All task is here ")
for tasks in list :
    print(tasks)  
for All_tasks in tasks :
    print("\n")
```

I want my list to print in the following pattern

```
call to do 
meeting 
sms
```

Comment: `task.split(",")` ?

Comment: 1) Don't use `list` as a variable name, it is a reserved word in python. 2) `split()` will split on spaces by default. You are using commas thus you should do `split(',')`

Comment: Please do not show your code and printout as a graphic. Put them in your question as text, so we can copy-and-paste into our own editors. That also makes it easier for people to search for your question later, so your question and the resulting answers will be more helpful to others. Also, the code in the graphic differs from the current code in your question. Which is it really?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The python function `split()` by default splits your text on spaces. You can add separator inside, for example: `task.split(',')` which means this function is going to split your text in list by commas.

[See more examples on w3schools.](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, Don't use "list" as a variable name.
And suppose your list, l=[aa,bb,cc,dd]. To print each element in a new line, you can do this-

```
for i in l:
   print(i)
```

```
It will give the following Output:-

aa
bb
cc
dd
```

Python creates a new line after each print command, so the above code will work fine.